# Android - Google Maps v2 - Retrieve and show position from a files containing coordinates

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, position

I would like to retrieve some positions (Latitude and Longitude) which are **contained in a TXT file**, and show them on my Map.

I know how to show my actual position, through the GPS of my tablet. I can update my position following this example.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener
{
    private LocationManager locationmanager;
    private GoogleMap googlemap;
    private Marker marker;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initializeMap();

    }

    private void initializeMap()
    {
        if(googlemap==null)
        {
            googlemap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Vous etes la").position(new LatLng(0,0)));

            if(googlemap==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to create map",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        locationmanager=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(locationmanager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            abonnementGps();
        }
        initializeMap();
    }

    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        desabonnementGps();
    }

    public void abonnementGps()
    {
        locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 19, this);
    }
    public void desabonnementGps()
    {
        locationmanager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
        final StringBuilder msg=new StringBuilder("Lati :");
        msg.append(location.getLatitude());
        msg.append("\nLogi :");
        msg.append(location.getLongitude());
        Toast.makeText(this, msg.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final LatLng latilongi=new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latilongi,19));
        marker.setPosition(latilongi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
    {
        if("gps".equals(provider))
        {
            desabonnementGps();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        if("gps".equals(provider))
        {
            abonnementGps();
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

I also know how to read a text file :

```
    // METHODE POUR LIRE UN FICHIER TEXTE
public String readText(String filepath) throws Exception
{
    String text="";
    try 
    {
        InputStream inputs=new FileInputStream(filepath);
        InputStreamReader inputsreader=new InputStreamReader(inputs);

        BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(inputsreader);
        String line;
        while((line=buffer.readLine())!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            text+=line+"\n";
        }
        buffer.close();
    } 
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }   
    return text;
}
```

For each line, I'd like to update my position, through the `onLocationChanged()`. But when I tried to call the method `onLocationChanged()` from `readText()`, my application was crashing.

**NB :** I changed the method public void onLocationChanged() to `public void onLocationChanged(LatLng latlong)` and the method public String readText(String str) to `public LatLng readText(String str)`.

I think my ideas are not clear and I mix everything I've just learned.
Can someone guide me please ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Best regards,

Tofuw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont call `onLocationChanged` manually, it gets called when your location changes so if you want to write to a file when a new location comes in you should do it in onLocationChanged

also you cannot change the method onLocationChanged to `onLocationChanged(LatLng latlong)` that is not how it works and you will not get the callbacks to the method. you need to keep it as is, you cant just go changing API methods like that

Comment: No, I won't write to a file, I wanna take the positions within the file to update the position on my map. That's why I wan't to call onLocationChanged manually. Or, is it an other way to change my map view ?

Comment: You cannot call onLocationChanged manually!! that is only called when you location changes. create another method that reads the location from file and then updates the position on the map

Comment: That is what I'll ask you ! Thanks :) I was a little stubborn with that onLocationChanged(). I'll try something with `setMyLocationEnabled()` and  `LatLng coordinates=coordinate;
  googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinates, 19));`

Comment: what are you going to do with `setMyLocationEnabled()` you cannot change the blue dot's position to a specific location you want it to go if thats what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new function to do the location change using the lat/lng from your text file:

```
public void MyLocationChanged(string slatlng ) 
    {
        string[] coord = slatlng.Split(',');
        final LatLng latilongi=new LatLng( Double.parseDouble( coord[ 0 ] ), Double.parseDouble( coord[ 1 ] ) );
        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latilongi,19));
        marker.setPosition(latilongi);
    }
```

Then just call this function from your text reading function, passing it the read line (assuming it is in the form:  latitude,longitude.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Andrew-OpenGeoCode. But is it what I've already tried. And it is not working. And also, tyczj says that it's not possible to call manually onLocationChanged.

Comment: Tofuw, my cut/paste mistake. I forgot to rename the function to something otherthan onLocationChanged(). I changed the name. You need both functions (event handler and direct call).

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded in solve my problem thanks to @Andrew-OpenGeoCode and @tyczj !

Here is my simple example, for those who are searching to retrieve and show positions from a files containing coordinates.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    // GoogleMaps
    private GoogleMap googlemap;
    private Marker marker;
    private TCPClient tcpclient;
    private Button bNavigation;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Connect to server - See innerClass connectTask below         
        try{ initializeMap(); }
        catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

        bNavigation=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bNavigation);
        bNavigation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                String filepath="/storage/sdcard0/TrameGPS/tramegps.txt";
                String texttosend="";
                // Reading the TXT
                try 
                {
                    texttosend=readText(filepath);
                }
                catch (Exception e1) 
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void initializeMap()
    {
        if(googlemap==null)
        {
            LatLng startposition=new LatLng(48.853,2.35);
            googlemap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            marker=googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("You are here !").position(startposition));
            googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startposition, 19));

            if(googlemap==null)
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to load map !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    // READING A TEXT FILE WHICH CONTAINS COORDINATES
    public String readText(String filepath) throws Exception
    {
        String text="";
        try 
        {
            InputStream inputs=new FileInputStream(filepath);
            InputStreamReader inputsreader=new InputStreamReader(inputs);

            BufferedReader buffer=new BufferedReader(inputsreader);
            String line;
            while((line=buffer.readLine())!=null)
            {
                String[]coordinates=line.split(",");

                if(coordinates[0].equals("$GPRMC"))
                {
                    String coord=coordinates[3]+","+coordinates[5];
                    changePosition(Double.parseDouble(coordinates[3]),Double.parseDouble(coordinates[5]));                  
                }
            }
            buffer.close();
        } 
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }   
        return text;
    }

    public void changePosition(Double a,Double b)
    {       
        final StringBuilder notification=new StringBuilder("Latitude : ");
        notification.append(a);
        notification.append("\nLongitude : ");
        notification.append(b);

        Toast.makeText(this, notification, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // UPDATE THE COORDINATES !!!! UPDATE THE COORDINATES !!!
        final LatLng latilongi=new LatLng(a, b);
        googlemap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latilongi, 19));
        marker.setPosition(latilongi);
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Once again, thanks to tyczj and Andrew-OpenGeoCode !

Best regards,

Tofuw

Comment: Tofuw, your welcome. Glad we have this community where we can all contribute to helping each other.